# Sorting latest news MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreach, sql-order-by

I'm trying sorting something according to its "published" date, where the four newest are the only ones that should be seen.

I'm doing that through MVC with a SQL database table, but for some reason it doesn't work the way it should and shows the whole list instead:

DataBaseClasses:

```
public class tblVidstedu
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Overskrift { get; set; }
    public string Tekst { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dato { get; set; }
}
```

Data Context:

```
public DbSet<DataBases.DataBaseClasses.tblVidstedu> Vidstedu { get; set; }
```

HomeController:

```
    public ActionResult VidsteDu()
    {
        var ViewModel = new Prøveeksamen.Models.InformationModel();

        // skal skrives på alle viewmodels
        ViewModel.Kontakt = db.Kontakt.ToList();
        List<tblKontakt> Kontakt = new List<tblKontakt>();

        ViewModel.Vidstedu = db.Vidstedu.ToList();

        List<tblVidstedu> Vidsteduliste = new List<tblVidstedu>();


       // !!!!!!!!! This is the part that i have problems with   !!!!!!!!!!! //
        Vidsteduliste = db.Vidstedu.OrderByDescending(v => v.Dato).Take(4).FirstOrDefault;

        return View(ViewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As first issue, we need to examine the order of query in this line:

```
Vidsteduliste = db.Vidstedu.OrderByDescending(v => v.Dato).Take(4).FirstOrDefault();
```

1. `OrderByDescending` based from `Dato` property
2. `Take` selects first 4 records from ordered records
3. `FirstOrDefault` takes first item from remaining 4 records, and returns **one record** in result set (instead of 4 that you want)

The second issue is instead of returning above result set, you're actually returning all records because of this `return` statement which doesn't set to return `Vidsteduliste`:

```
return View(ViewModel);
```

while previously `ViewModel` assigned with this line:

```
ViewModel.Vidstedu = db.Vidstedu.ToList(); // returns all records from 'Vidstedu'
```

Since you want to show top 4 records ordered by most recent `Dato` value, just remove all unnecessary list instantiations like `List<tblVidstedu> Vidsteduliste = new List<tblVidstedu>();` and return those records directly from controller action:

```
ViewModel.Vidstedu = db.Vidstedu.OrderByDescending(v => v.Dato).Take(4).ToList();

return View(ViewModel);
```

Then you can use `foreach` loop to show records stored in `Vidstedu` list on view page.